# Explanation for equality $A - B = A \cap \overline B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider:
$$A - B = A \cap \overline B$$

Why is it true? Isn't $A \cap \overline B$ equals to $A$?

Comment: What if  $B=A$ ?

Comment: Have tried proving the double inclusion?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: I did drew a diagram and it looks like the intersection is $A$.

Comment: OK. I know where is my mistake. I drew it wrong :)

Comment: This leads me to ask: can you say exactly what you think these two expressions mean? There may be a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\cap \overline B$ equals $A$ exactly if $A$ is a subset of $\overline B$. Unless you know something very specific about $A$ and $B$, you can't say that will be the case.

For example, if $A=\{5,17\}$ and $B=\{5,17,39\}$, then $A\cap\overline B$ is the set of things that are *both* either 5 or 17, *and at the same time* are neither 5, 17, nor 39 -- that is, $\{5,17\}\cap\overline{\{5,17,39\}}=\varnothing$, which is definitely not the same as $\{5,17\}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$x\in A\setminus B\implies x\in A\;\;\text{and}\;\;x\notin B$$

$$x\in A\cap B^c\implies x\in A\;\;\text{and}\;\;x\notin B$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition $A- B$ is the set of $x$ that belongs to $A$ and not in $B$ so $x$ belongs to $A$ and to $\overline B$ hence
$$A-B=A\cap \overline B$$

Comment: Don't know why someone down-voted your answer, but thanks Sami.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} x\in A- B &\iff x \in A \land x\notin B \iff x \in A \land x\in B^c \iff x \in A\cap B^c\end{align}$$

$$\therefore A-B = A\cap B^c$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
A-B=\{x : x\in A\text{ and } x\notin B\} = \{x: x\in A \text{ and not }(x\in B)\} = A\cap \overline{B}
$$